# $.method, how it can be used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

While I was reading some code like this:

```
jQuery.method(
    {
        '__method': 'SubmitWorkItem', 
        '__smsnotify':jQuery('#sendmsg').attr('checked') ? 'true': 'false', 
        'long:workItem': WorkItemId, 
        'int?:next': NextNodeId, 'string:actors': Actors 
    }, 
    function (txt) {
        eval('var ret = ' + txt);
    }
);
```

I have searched jquery.com, but no result.

I have never used this 'method' before. How it can be used? Where does it come from?

Comment: It's entirely possible it's just not part of the API. Where'd this code you were reading come from?

Comment: It's entirely possible that it isn't even part of jQuery and you're looking at a third party extension.

Comment: @Quentin - Having searched through the jQuery source, it seems you're right.

Comment: @Quentin The refrence js file is just jquery 1.51,this is the only refrence js file.Perphaps somebody extened the jquery,i have no idea.

Comment: @Quentin  You are right. I found the extension at the end of the jquery 1.51 file.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3118429 jQuery 1.51 is positively ancient, so it might be a long-unused internal function or maybe a deprecated and removed API. (I'm guessing the former because removing functions without changing major library versions is unusual.)